# I need an excel formula that can calculate the restock or pat test amounts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I need a formula that will measure: If amount is less than restock amount then show restock | if amount is less than restock amount but there are items available then show pat test | if more than restock amount then show ok

Comment: Why don't you set up a simple google sheet with some sample data, so people will have something to work with.  You'll probably attract more people to help you that way, too.  Excel and Sheets aren't 100% compatible, but they are usually pretty close, and this will be a simple enough formula that it will be fine to set up in Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this demo in Sheets:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ChvT8xvdK5r7K-mFEu3Lh9KwHWxuURi03x5mNsDHDQU/edit#gid=0

So you have three conditions:

```
amount > restock
amount < restock AND items available > 0
amount < restock AND items available = 0
```

You can ignore the last part of the third condition as long as items available is never negative OR you don't care if you trigger the condition if items available is negative.

So in a pseudo code:

```
IF(
  amount > restock, "OK",
  IF (
    items available = 0, 
    "RESTOCK",
    "PAT TEST"

  )
)
```

Be aware that as formulated the conditions exclude cases where amount = restock, so you make the first condition `amount >= restock`.

Let me know if that does what you are after.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!  In the future, you can get better response (and probably avoid some of those downvotes) if you will: include some sample data, especially in a format that people can use directly or do a simple copy/paste with; your desired outcomes, also in an accessible format; and what you have tried so far, including attempted formulas or code.  Good luck!

Comment: Also, you should probably state the version of Excel you're using, since some formulas are only available in later versions.